ADF Pipeline restrictions or performance limitations
In Azure data factory, I have a quite a simple pipeline with the web activity.
1.) It gets the data (paginated) and
2.) Sends it to a power automate for further processing.
I have the 'Until' loop activity with the controlling expression
@less(variables('varItemCount'), 100)

and inside of it is the following.

The web activity 'Get Data' navigates to a URL
@concat(pipeline().globalParameters.baseUrl, 
    'data/v1/endPoint?per_Page=100&page=', 
  variables('varPageCount'))

The problem is that after page 11, the pipeline gets frozen and does not move further.
(Power automate, stores data in the database, and I can confirm that it does so)
There is no errors, and pipeline does not stop.  It just sits in the "executing" state forever. and the outputs shows that it stuck on the page 11.   I know the data I am reading should come in 63 or 64 pages.
How can I mitigate this problem ?
For reference, I am including the pipeline code here (Removing the security info)


{
    "name": "PL_MyPipeLine",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Run until",
                "description": "Loop over paginated list",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@less(variables('varItemCount'), 100)\n",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Data",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "method": "GET",
                                "headers": {
                                    "US-Customer-Api-Key": {
                                        "value": "@string(json(string(activity('get Service Security').output.value)).customerApiKey)",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                },
                                "url": {
                                    "value": "@concat(pipeline().globalParameters.baseUrl, \n        'endPoint-base-elements?per_Page=100&page=', variables('varPageCount'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "authentication": {
                                    "type": "Basic",
                                    "username": {
                                        "value": "@string(json(string(activity('get Service Security').output.value)).userName)",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "password": {
                                        "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                                        "store": {
                                            "referenceName": "KeyVaultLink",
                                            "type": "LinkedServiceReference",
                                            "parameters": {
                                                "AZKeyVaultName": {
                                                    "value": "@pipeline().globalParameters.AZKeyVaultName",
                                                    "type": "Expression"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "secretName": "integration-password"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "tempResult",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Data",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varTempResult",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@union(\n    variables('varFinalResult'), array(json(activity('Get Data').output.Response))\n)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ResponseSize",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Data",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varItemCount",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@length(\n    array(json(activity('Get Data').output.Response))\n)\n\n",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Current Page",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "ResponseSize",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varCurrentPage",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@add(variables('varPageCount'), 1)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Reset Page Count",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Current Page",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varPageCount",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('varCurrentPage')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "tempTolal",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "ResponseSize",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varTempSize",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@add(variables('varTotalSize'),variables('varItemCount') )",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Update total size",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "tempTolal",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varTotalSize",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('varTempSize')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Reset final Result",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "tempResult",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "varFinalResult",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('varTempResult')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Power automate flow_copy1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Data",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "PL_ExecutePowerAutomate",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true,
                                "parameters": {
                                    "plP_powerUrl": {
                                        "value": "@pipeline().globalParameters.PowerAutomate_BaseUrl",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "plP_jsonBody": {
                                        "value": "@activity('Get Data').output.Response",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Final result size",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Run until",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "varTotalResultSize",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@length(variables('varFinalResult'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "varResponse": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "varPageCount": {
                "type": "Integer",
                "defaultValue": 11
            },
            "varItemCount": {
                "type": "Integer",
                "defaultValue": 100
            },
            "varTempResult": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "varCurrentPage": {
                "type": "Integer",
                "defaultValue": 1
            },
            "varTotalSize": {
                "type": "Integer",
                "defaultValue": 0
            },
            "varTempSize": {
                "type": "Integer"
            },
            "varFinalResult": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "varTotalResultSize": {
                "type": "Integer"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "SyncFolder"
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}




Is the variable gets updated from web activity's output? and did you check the web activity's output at the page 11? Can you provide your pipeline JSON by masking your credentials for better understanding of the issue?

Yes, the variable gets updated.  This pipeline, is copied/pasted from various others I have for this vendor, just different endpoint.  All of them work fine, but they don't have so much data to span so many pages .. 4-5-6 pages, usually.  This is the one of such large capacity.
I included the json code of the pipeline

I have reproduced the pipeline with the same pipeline JSON that you have provided, and it is working fine for me.
The Until activity will execute the inner activities until the expression results to True. You have mentioned that the pipeline is in execution state from the start, so your condition in the Until activity might be resulting to False in every iteration.

I have made the condition as False and executed the above pipeline design. You can see the value of varPageCount is increasing from 11.

Recheck the pipeline by publishing and you can try to decode this by executing the pipeline only by involving the activities which are incrementing the varPageCount value by 1.
